# Where is the "create new app" button?

Tags: facebook

In this [tutorial](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/tutorial/) it mentions the "create new app" button. But I can not find such a button. It says go to the [developer page](http://developers.facebook.com/apps). But when I click on the developer page link it takes me back to my own facebook page (the page I get after logging on facebook).
My page is not a personal page but a page created for my website. Does that make a difference? Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: This is off-topic-ish for stackoverflow and ... **trying it** would tell you the answer, but I suspect the answer is "yes" and you need to use a personal facebook account; works for me.

Comment: Check out my answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15149335/cant-create-facebook-app/15150241#15150241
I was having similar problems as you

Answer (score 3):

Add the The [Developer Application](https://developers.facebook.com/), After that you'll be able to [create a new app](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/appsonfacebook/tutorial/).