# Can't Create Facebook App

Tags: facebook-apps, facebook-app-requests

First time trying to create a Facebook app.  Browsed to https://developers.facebook.com/apps and it had a link for to register before creating a link where you just accept the T&C's.   Now it says, "Create an app to start..."   But there is no button to click to create app.

Comment: Disabling your adblock should solve it. such a nice move from facebook to track us, don't you think so?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I was having this SAME exact problem **just** now. I have a verified personal account (email and credit card) and I couldn't see the button. This is what I was getting:
[image]

I was at my wits end after 5 hours of reading similar questions and started pulling my eyelashes out...because I have no hair. I tried:

- Turning off AdBlock
- Testing in multiple browsers and OS'
- Inspecting the area with Chrome Inspector...which turned up an empty #DeveleperAppDashHeader div
- Praying to the rain gods

Eventually, I became so desperate that I started typing random urls, and this one, by the Odin's Raven, worked: http://developers.facebook.com/setup

It creates a popup window that will let you get the ball rolling. Let me know if this worked, because I am damn near ready to hump my chair with excitement.

Also, I suspect that this is a bug...because if I can create an App using this link but not through the dev dashboard, then something is up.

Comment: I've added my page - after that button become available

Comment: I am facing the same issue spend whole day searching for Create New App Button.  Tried this above mentioned link.No luck for me yet :(   It seems facebook has taken note of your post and make it more harder to find.

Comment: So it's 3 years later, but now it would seem that following these steps will yield a 60 day token rather than a token that never expires.

Comment: It's 6 years later, and https://developers.facebook.com/setup now redirects to https://developers.facebook.com/apps/?action=create which unfortunately no longer helps :(

Answer (score 1):

Here is an explanation about how to create a new app - http://ftutorials.com/create-facebook-app/

First you should check that you are not trying to create a new application from business account. You can create new app only from a facebook account of a real user.

Also there is some facebook bug, that after you click on "Create app", nothing happens, but your app is created.