# New app registration

Tags: facebook

I'm trying to create a new app for facebook, I'm using my real account for that. But i've got no "New App" Button on this page https://developers.facebook.com/

I have tryed to setup my company profile on a settings page, but strong validation doesn't give me a chance to enter my patpal account details.

It says that I must to enter valid paypal email.... What is it?

Comment: Check out my answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15149335/cant-create-facebook-app/15150241#15150241
I was having similar problems as you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oh my!
I did it.

The point was in creating my page (link in the bottom of the page). After that link for creating new app become visible.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to create an app via https://developers.facebook.com/apps

As far as a paypal email you would sign up for paypal at: www.paypal.com